# Bash - Extracting just the date and time from a string variable with other surrounding text being excluded

Tags: string, bash, date, match, extract

I'm new to sed and have been trying to use it with no luck yet in this case.

I'm reading through a log file and I store the prior line into a variable so that I can extract out the date if needed.

variable string example:

jcl/jclnt.log-[05/06/20 16:42:52.964]:jclnt ST:

I'm only wanting the date and timestamp in the square brackets. I want to ignore the characters before and after. The date and time format are always the same length and format. I can match on it with a regex, just not sure how to extract it from a variable into a new variable with only the data inside the square brackets.

I tried something like this:
 priordate= echo "$prior" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you remove the space before your `echo`.

```
echo "jcl/jclnt.log-[05/06/20 16:42:52.964]:jclnt ST:" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'
05/06/20 16:42:52.964
```

and then make the statement thus: `priordate=$(echo ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bash's native regular expression matching. This is a quick and dirty regular expression that just relies on capturing whatever is between `[` and `]`. You can certainly make it more specific if necessary.

```
#!/bin/bash

s="jcl/jclnt.log-[05/06/20 16:42:52.964]:jclnt ST:"
pattern="\[(.*)\]"

if [[ "${s}" =~ $pattern ]]
then
        date_time="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi

echo "${date_time}"
```

Output:

```
05/06/20 16:42:52.964
```

Comment: ```priordate=$(echo "$prior" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}')```
OR
```priordate=$(echo "$prior" | sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\).*/\1/'```